# barplot in pandas doesn't work with non-numerical data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called breed in a pandas df that contains the breed of cat, for example Siamese, Russian Blue, etc.

I want to return a bar chart that displays the number of times each breed is listed in the table. I tried df['breed'].plot.bar(), but I'm getting the error "Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot".

Answer (score 2):

You can use **value_counts**, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

catTypes = ['siamese','russian_blue','tabby']

# Generate dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['breed']=np.random.choice(catTypes, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
# value_counts will give the count of each breed
df['breed'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=0)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are make use of `countplot()` from seaborn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.countplot('breed', data = df)
```